# Java - Purpose of service provider in interface based frameworks?

Tags: java, interface

I have listed below notes from 'Effective Java' and the code it references.

My question -

> why does the author feel service provider interface saves having to
>   register by class name and instantiate reflectively ? Can't the
>   registration API in the static factory 'providers' be modified to
>   register instances of 'services' instead of 'service providers'?

So do -

```
// Maps service names to services
private static final Map<String, Service> services =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Service>();
public static final String DEFAULT_PROVIDER_NAME = "<def>";

// Provider registration API
public static void registerDefaultService( Service s) {
    registerService(DEFAULT_PROVIDER_NAME, s);
}
public static void registerService(String name, Service s){
    services.put(name, s);
}
```

instead of the example from the text below.

Excerpt from the text -

> An optional fourth component of a service provider framework is a
>   service provider interface, which providers implement to create
>   instances of their service implementation. In the absence of a service
>   provider interface, implementations are registered by class name and
>   instantiated reflectively (Item 53). In the case of JDBC, Connection
>   plays the part of the service interface, DriverManager.registerDriver
>   is the provider registration API, DriverManager.getConnection is the
>   service access API, and Driver is the service provider interface.

And here's the code -

```
// Service provider framework sketch

// Service interface
public interface Service {
    ... // Service-specific methods go here
}

// Service provider interface
public interface Provider {
    Service newService();
}

// Noninstantiable class for service registration and access
public class Services {
    private Services() { }  // Prevents instantiation (Item 4)

    // Maps service names to services
    private static final Map<String, Provider> providers =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Provider>();
    public static final String DEFAULT_PROVIDER_NAME = "<def>";

    // Provider registration API
    public static void registerDefaultProvider(Provider p) {
        registerProvider(DEFAULT_PROVIDER_NAME, p);
    }
    public static void registerProvider(String name, Provider p){
        providers.put(name, p);
    }

    // Service access API
    public static Service newInstance() {
        return newInstance(DEFAULT_PROVIDER_NAME);
    }
    public static Service newInstance(String name) {
        Provider p = providers.get(name);
        if (p == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "No provider registered with name: " + name);
        return p.newService();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The provider in this case is a factory, and all the usual reasons for using a factory apply. Different service implementations might need very different construction code, and using a factory means the registry doesn't need to know about the implementation details, just the bare minimum needed to specify the service's behavior.

Comment: Thanks much! Although my question remains - the factory doesnt necessarily preclude reflection, right? I am missing something!

Comment: @BiAct Not sure what you mean by "preclude". Generally, you'll still need reflection somewhere to instantiate the factory, and then the factory won't need reflection for the service objects.

Comment: I guess I am not clear how this framework will actually be used. 

For e.g., say I wrote OracleService implementing Service Interface, and then OracleServiceProvider implementing the Provider Interface, and there is a client class OracleDataDictionary that needs OracleService - when would the registerProvider be called? I cant visualize how this will play out in a sequence. Any guidance you offer would be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the benefits with service provider interfaces could be a loose coupling, and when it is actually required, between the service provider instances and their consumers.